# About URL that doesn't really exist

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, request-uri

How can I create a URL that doesn't really exist? For example, https://twitter.com/i/notifications **- works.** When you remove the **/notifications** from the link you get https://twitter.com/i/ **- Does not work.** but this URL **/i/** doesn't really exist.

How do I make something like that?

Comment: Something like what?

Comment: How are you trying to do .. is there any issue you are facing..??

Comment: That is called a Rewriting a Request.  You can search for that

Comment: Is it anything to do with .htaccess or PHP? @MiltoxBeyond

Comment: Yes.  If you use apache its the .htaccess, nginx uses the config files, iis uses URLRewrite.  Most servers have a way of doing it

Comment: .htaccess  trick , it's called "Pretty Urls"

Comment: Why do you claim the URL "does not really exist"? When _does_ a URL "exist" in your eyes?

Comment: @arkascha as  I say it's called pretty urls , which the URL doesn't exist is the category or something similar to it

Comment: @Kain I asked the OP, not you. I know what if generally referred to by "pretty URLs".

Answer (score 1):

You can create an .htaccess file that routes ALL requests through a single PHP file and then use the logic in that PHP file to determine whether the url exists or not.  For example, you could use my CodeIgniter .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|fonts|js|robots\.txt|test)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This lets you still specify images, css, js, etc. that doesn't get remapped but any urls that don't start with those strings will be routed to index.php.  Within index.php, you can inspect the query string to determine how to handle the urls and decide if they exist or not.

```
// code in index.php, modify to suit
switch ($_SERVER["PATH_INFO") { // you might also check out REQUEST_URI
  case "foo":
    // do blah blah blah
    break;
  case "bar":
    // do other blah blah blah
    break;
  default:
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    echo "Sorry but that page was not found";
}
```

Comment: Your `RewriteRule` is passing the requested URL-path as _path information_ (ie. `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`), not the query string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use URL rewriting by editing `.htaccess` file. If `.htaccess` is not there then you can create one on project root directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?Some-text-goes-here/([0-9]+)$ /picture.php?id=$1
```

the above will convert `url.com/picture.php?id=51` to `picture.php/Some-text-goes-here/51`

In same way you can use yours strtagy.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to everyone for helping!

Final solution: `RewriteRule ^/?i(/.*)?/company /company [L,NC]`

Comment: You don't need to add `/?`. `RewriteRule ^i(/.*)?/company /company [L,NC]`. It would be fine without that. Both works. It seems to be redundant. So, thought to give you a suggestion.

Comment: The `/?` (slash prefix, made _optional_ in this regex) is only required if this rule was to be used in a server config or VirtualHost context. In per-directory `.htaccess` files the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` pattern does not start with a slash, which is why it is made _optional_ here.